# Push notification not determined

Tags: ios, ios8, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter

In ios 10 there is `UNUserNotificationCenter` class and method `getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler` which gives you `UNNotificationSettings` object and you can check is user has been ever asked for push notifications permissions.Is there a way to achieve this for iOS 9 and iOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way. That functionality is available starting from ios 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
let notificationType = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()!.types

if notificationType == UIUserNotificationType.None {
  // Push notifications are disabled in setting by user.
} else {
 // Push notifications are enabled in setting by user.
}

if notificationType != UIUserNotificationType.None {
  // Push notifications are enabled in setting by user.
}

if notificationType == UIUserNotificationType.Badge {
  // the application may badge its icon upon a notification being received
}

if notificationType == UIUserNotificationType.Sound {
  // the application may play a sound upon a notification being received
}

if notificationType == UIUserNotificationType.Alert {
  // the application may display an alert upon a notification being received
}
```